# CrashReporter dialog doesn't show when mac app crashes

Tags: macos, cocoa, crash-reports

I have a Mac app store app that just silently disappears when it crashes. It doesn't show the CrashReporter dialog to give the user a chance to report the crash to Apple.

I see the same behavior on multiple machines. Is there any known reason why this might happen?

According to [TN2123](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html):

> In addition, if the program that crashed is running as a logged in GUI
>   user, CrashReporter will present the user with a dialog asking them
>   whether they want to submit a bug report to Apple

What does "running as a logged in GUI user" mean? Does a window have to be visible?

**Update:**

I was reading the [manpage for ReportCrash](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ReportCrash.8.html), and found the following:

> For application crashes (but not background process crashes)
>   ReportCrash will display a dialog notifying the user that the
>   application unexpectedly quit and offering to reopen the application
>   or send the report to Apple.  For developers, the behavior of this
>   dialog can be adjusted using
>   /Developer/Applications/Utilities/CrashReporterPrefs.app which is
>   installed as part of the developer tools.

I ran CrashReporterPrefs and changed my CrashReporter mode to Developer. When I ran the app and triggered the crash, the CrashReporter dialog was shown!

So I guess the question now is: **What's the difference between an "application" crash and a "background process" crash?**

Comment: Is the app calling `exit()` or `_exit()`? Could it actually be quitting itself, so that it's a controlled shutdown as opposed to a crash? Is anything written to the console log when this happens?

Comment: @KenThomases - It's definitely a crash, because the crash reports are generated. The system log shows the crash report being saved as well. The problem I'm having is just that the CrashReporter dialog is not displayed, which means the user never gets a chance to submit the report.

Comment: Is this only when you're running it under Xcode, or is it also when you run the app yourself from the Finder?

Comment: @PeterHosey - It's when the app is run from Finder

Comment: "running as a logged in GUI user" means a user that is logged into the machine via the GUI :-). Seriously, it is any user that is not a daemon-type user (such as `www`, `_mdnsresponder`, `_windowserver` etc etc). Your app, launched by you in the Finder, is running as a logged-in GUI user. No window has to be visible for this to be the case. You can see which user owns each process in Activity Monitor.

Comment: It also excludes logged-in CLI users—those logged in via SSH or telnet.

Comment: The crash reporter dialog is only presented for GUI apps. It's not presented for command-line tools or the like. (There's a developer tool, CrashReporterPrefs, to change that but the default is to not show it for tools.)

Comment: Thanks.. Any thoughts on why this is happening? It's not a command-line tool, and I confirmed via ps that the app is run as the logged in user. Is the dialog part of the crashed process, or does some other system process display it?

Comment: @pepsi: Does your app have either `LSUIElement` or `LSBackgroundOnly` turned on, or is it a normal user-facing app?

Comment: @PeterHosey : Yes LSUIElement is turned on. I turned it off, ran the test, and the crash report dialog showed up. Thanks! If you put this in an answer, I'll mark it accepted. On a side note, I wonder if there's any way to get the dialog without turning off LSUIElement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app uses LSUIElement or LSBackgroundOnly, it's a “background process” for the purpose of determining whether to show the Crash Reporter. (Other “background processes” include UNIX-land daemons, such as the Apache web server, and processes started from SSH or telnet connections.)

Answer (score 0):

Since CrashReporterPrefs no longer comes with developer tools, you can change the behavior to show the dialog for daemons by running this command in the Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType Developer
```