# Why doesn't dereferencing null crash my program?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I wrote the following code to induce a crash (I was testing out some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359966/crashreporter-dialog-doesnt-show-when-mac-app-crashes) with CrashReporter):

```
int *nullp = NULL;
int val = *nullp;    
NSLog(@"Hello world %d", val);
```

In a brand new project (I put it in the app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`) it crashes as expected. But when I add it to one of my existing projects, it doesn't crash! In fact, it ends up printing "Hello world 0" to the system log.

This doesn't make any sense to me. Why doesn't the null dereference cause a crash?

Comment: Other options for causing a crash, if you need them: [Make C crash without casting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556183/make-c-crash-without-casting)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dereferncing NULL has undefined behavior, it doesn't have to cause crash.

That being said, if you have different compiler options in the two project you have a good chance to get different behavior for those cases. See this [LLVM blog post](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) about undefined behaviors.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea. That link helped me get it to crash: "If you're using an LLVM-based compiler, you can dereference a 'volatile' null pointer to get a crash if that's what you're looking for, since volatile loads and stores are generally not touched by the optimizer."

Comment: That post opened my eyes when I first read it  (about a month or two ago)

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out to those who are very not familiar with C that this means you need to declare `nullp` as `volatile int *nullp = NULL;`.

Comment: The advice to use volatile variables is the only bad thing in that post. If you actually want to force a crash under Clang, use `__builtin_trap()`.

Comment: Or, more portably, `raise(SIGTRAP)` or `abort()`. The latter is [what Clang does on architectures that don't have a trap instruction](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#opt_ftrap-function).

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behaviour - ie there is no rule that says it *must* crash your app.

Different compilers will give different results - and different compiler options (eg release vs debug configs) will also affect things.

If you are trying to force a crash you could always start writing to a null pointer...

Comment: While writing to a null pointer is *more likely* to generate a crash, it's still not guaranteed. Undefined also means unpredictable, at least with 100% assurance, unless you're intimately familiar with the compiler and processor architecture - and neither one changes.

Answer (score -1):

int *nullp = NULL; or int *nullp = 0 are same it means pointer nullp is not pointing a memory location. Since NULL == 0 it is printing Zero and not crashing